# What does it mean "mixed case" versus "camel case" versus "pascal case" versus ...?

Tags: case, mixed

I am not really sure what is mixed case, camel case nor pase, could someone explain me thanks

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Pascal-Case-and-Camel-Case

Comment: there's also snake_case, which uses underscores to split words.

Answer (score 2):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx:

Pascal case is when the first letter of each word is capitalised. Camel case is similar, but instead, the first letter is lowercase:

Pascal:

```c
HelloWorld // <--- pascal case
```

Camel:

```c
helloWorld // <--- camel case
```

Mixed case:
I'm assuming this is just a mix of anything in no particular pattern:

Mayb3SOMEthINGlikETHiS

Mixed case strings must also contain numbers: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mixed-case.1473910/

Comment: Actual, in Pascal based tools like Delphi, it is called camelcase, not pascal case.